# Foreach hash with Perl template toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I am using Perl template toolkit for rendering my data.
This is the hash that I am passing to the template

```
'location' => {
               '1' => {
                       'nmi' => 'QB13557343'
                },
               '2' => {
                       'nmi' => 'QB13559843'
                },
             },
```

and in the template I am looping this hash to get the result but its not displaying 
The code in the template is:

```
[% FOREACH loc IN location %]

    <p>NMI: [% loc.nmi %][% location.loc.nmi %]


[% END %]
```

I tried both loc.nmi and location.loc.nmi but not getting any result.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a hash and not an array. Try to iterate over the keys.

```
[% FOREACH key IN location.keys %]
    <p>NMI: [% location.$key.nmi %]</p>
[% END %]
```